# lowercase everything except content between single quotes - perl

Tags: perl

Is there a way in perl to replace all text in input line except ones within single quotes(There could be more than one) using regex, I have achieved this using the code below but would like to see if it can be done with regex and map.

```
while (<>) {
    my $m=0;
    for (split(//)) { 
        if (/'/ and ! $m) {
            $m=1;
            print;
        }
        elsif (/'/ and $m) {
            $m=0;
            print;
        }
        elsif ($m) {
            print;
        }
        else {
            print lc;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
**Sample input:**

and (t.TARGET_TYPE='RAC_DATABASE' or (t.TARGET_TYPE='ORACLE_DATABASE' and t.TYPE_QUALIFIER3 != 'racinst'))

**Sample output:**

and (t.target_type='RAC_DATABASE' or (t.target_type='ORACLE_DATABASE' and t.type_qualifier3 != 'racinst'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and include sample input and output. It's hard to understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: Can quotes be nested, can they be escaped, does an apostrophe count as a quote, and what should happen in those cases?

Comment: $str=~s/(.*?)(".*?")/sprintf("%s%s",lc $1, $2)/ge;    #this will do it

Comment: @simbabque Thanks, I have added sample input and output now.

Comment: @DavidO The input I am working on is SQL and the ones I have do not have nested quotes and there are no apostrophes.

Comment: @hoffmeister Will try that out, thanks.

Comment: So you want to make the SQL commands lowercase?

Comment: @simbabque yes, all the text except ones within single quotes

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have found that the general answer to the question "Can X be done in Perl with a regex?" is "yes".

Comment: @SilvioMayolo usually though the answer to the question "Should this be done in Perl with a regex" is "no" though. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give this a shot. All one regexp.

```
$str =~ s/(?:^|'[^']*')\K[^']*/lc($&)/ge;
```

Or, cleaner and more documented (this is semantically equivalent to the above)

```
$str =~ s/
  (?:
    ^     | # Match either the start of the string, or
    '[^']*' # some text in quotes.
  )\K       # Then ignore that part,
            # because we want to leave it be.
  [^']*     # Take the text after it, and
            # lowercase it.
  /lc($&)/gex;
```

The `g` flag tells the regexp to run as many times as necessary. `e` tells it that the substitution portion (`lc($&)`, in our case) is Perl code, not just text. `x` lets us put those comments in there so that the regexp isn't total gibberish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you play too hard with regexp for such a simple job?

Why not get the kid 'split' for it today?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>)
{
    @F = split "'";
    @F = map { $_ % 2 ? $F[$_] : lc $F[$_] } (0..@F);
    print join "'", @F;
}
```

The above is for understanding. We often join the latter two lines reasonably into:

```
print join "'", map { $_ % 2 ? $F[$_] : lc $F[$_] } (0..@F);
```

Or enjoy more, making it a one-liner? (in bash shell) In concept, it looks like:

```
perl -pF/'/ -e 'join "'", map { $_ % 2 ? $F[$_] : lc $F[$_] } (0..@F);' YOUR_FILE
```

In reality, however, we need to respect the shell and do some escape (hard) job:

```
perl -pF/\'/ -e 'join "'"'"'", map { $_ % 2 ? $F[$_] : lc $F[$_] } (0..@F);' YOUR_FILE
```

(The single-quoted single quote needs to become 5 letters: `'"'"'`)

If it doesn't help your job, it helps sleep.

Answer (score 0):

One more variant with Perl one-liner. I'm using hex \x27 for single quotes

```
$ cat sql_str.txt
and (t.TARGET_TYPE='RAC_DATABASE' or (t.TARGET_TYPE='ORACLE_DATABASE' and t.TYPE_QUALIFIER3 != 'racinst'))

$ perl -ne ' { @F=split(/\x27/); for my $val (0..$#F) { $F[$val]=lc($F[$val]) if $val%2==0 } ; print join("\x27",@F) } ' sql_str.txt
and (t.target_type='RAC_DATABASE' or (t.target_type='ORACLE_DATABASE' and t.type_qualifier3 != 'racinst'))

$
```